# Is there something like "afterChange" event instead of "change" in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly.js

I am trying to make source data for X and Y axes in a Plotly chart update automatically whenever the user selects a value from a dropdown corresponding to particular axis.

There is a problem in the event listeners (last two rows of below code):

```
function restyle(chart_div, update_data) {
            console.log(update_data.x);
            Plotly.restyle(chart_div, update_data);

    };

var update_data = {
    x: [columns[controls.x_axis_dropdown.value]], 
    y: [columns[controls.y_axis_dropdown.value]], 
};

controls['x_axis_dropdown'].addEventListener("change", function(){restyle(chart_div, update_data)});
controls['y_axis_dropdown'].addEventListener("change", function(){restyle(chart_div, update_data)});
```

The problem is that currently whenever the user changes the dropdown value, the `restyle` function is called BEFORE the dropdown value is indeed changed. As a result, the chart stays the same.

How do I make the `restyle` function be called after the dropdown value is changed? So instead of "change" event on the event listeners, I would need something like "afterChange" event.

Comment: The "change" event is fired by a dropdown *after* its value changes. You are mistaken.

Comment: It will fire after, but `update_data` - the parameter - will still contain data from before the change. Hence,  the `console.log(update_data.x)` above will still print old data.

Comment: Just a side note: `change` callbacks usually provides `arguments` with the **new values**. The problem in your code is that you are referencing a variable that likely gets updated later.

Comment: Your code snippet is also invalid -- there is the `})` at the end, context is entirely missing, `chart_div` is not defined, and there is no telling how many times your event listener are attached, and in any case assigning the value of your dropdown controls *once* (to the `update_data` object) is doing exactly what it is supposed to -- the value is just the value that the control had when the assignment took place, why are you expecting any other value in your `restyle` function?

Comment: @ amn Thanks for your comments and corrections. However, I am not "expecting any other value" - I am aware that is wrong approach and am looking for another, as hopefully is evident in my original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your issue should be with this part

```
var update_data = {
    x: [columns[controls.x_axis_dropdown.value]], 
    y: [columns[controls.y_axis_dropdown.value]], 
};
```

the x and y values are constant since update is set only once

try changing your code to :

```
function restyle(chart_div) {
      var update_data = {
           x: [columns[controls.x_axis_dropdown.value]], 
           y: [columns[controls.y_axis_dropdown.value]], 
       };
            console.log(update_data.x);
            Plotly.restyle(chart_div, update_data);

    };

controls['x_axis_dropdown'].addEventListener("change", function(){restyle(chart_div)});
controls['y_axis_dropdown'].addEventListener("change", function(){restyle(chart_div)});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to get the value directly from the dropdown element. Use the event object with which the callback function is invoked to retrieve the target element's relevant value.

```
controls['y_axis_dropdown'].addEventListener("change", function(event){
    const update_data = event.target.whatever_data;
    restyle(chart_div, update_data)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a timeout, and it works great:

```js
document.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  /*
   * We use a timeout here to simulate an "afterChange" event.
   * This allows us to read directly from the DOM instead of
   * having to read from the event, which would require a lengthier code
   * to account for all elements we might want to read.
   */
  setTimeout(function() {
    // Do something after change.
  }, 100);
});
```

Comment: It should be noted that this solution still has a race condition. In most cases this will work, however in the event that the code runs longer than 100 milliseconds, the code in the timeout will still execute too soon.